# How can we automate the tag disambiguation process?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that the precise meaning of some tags on Stack Overflow is not intuitively obvious - for example, the ambiguous [translate](/questions/tagged/translate) and [translation](/questions/tagged/translation) tags could easily be confused with [machine-translation](/questions/tagged/machine-translation) or [code-translation](/questions/tagged/code-translation). As far as I know, there is not yet any way to automatically identify ambiguously-tagged questions. In the future, will it possible to turn a tag with an ambiguous name into a "disambiguation tag", like [the disambiguation pages on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:Disambiguation), so that users would be presented with a list of unambiguous tags whenever they used an ambiguously-named tag?

Tag disambiguation requests [appear to be fairly frequent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=disambiguate+tags) on Meta Stack Overflow, so I think this would be a very useful feature to implement.

Comment: We generally call out such tags here on meta and go on a clean-up spree instead. Create tags that are not ambiguous, retag, etc.

Comment: If I could, I would turn the `translation` tag into a disambiguation tag for the `source-to-source` and `natural-language-translation` tags, since it could refer to either of these two things. If such a feature existed, users could then be prompted to replace these ambiguous tags with less ambiguous ones.

Comment: There is no such feature. We can make a tag a synonym for another (always redirecting), or we can ban it (can never be used). But generally we retag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it would be better to turn "banned" tags into "disambiguation" tags, if such a feature were possible - users who try to use a blacklisted tag could be presented with a list of alternative (and less ambiguous) tag names.

Comment: Then make that a feature request, perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This already is a feature request.