# How can we disambiguate the [translate] and [translation] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [translate](/questions/tagged/translate) and [translation](/questions/tagged/translation) tags have different tag descriptions: one of them is about translation of natural languages while the other is about translation of programming languages. Nonetheless, the wording of both of these tags is inherently ambiguous, and it would be better to disambiguate both of these tags into [machine-translation](/questions/tagged/machine-translation) and [code-translation](/questions/tagged/code-translation).

However, the [the Stack Exchange Network does not yet have a tag disambiguation feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166976/is-it-possible-to-create-disambiguation-tags-on-stack-overflow), so I'm not sure if we can accomplish this task easily.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason we would need any kind of tag about code translation.  Seems meta-ish to me.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Code translation is synonymous with [source to-source compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler). Why would this topic be considered "meta-ish"?

Comment: @psubsee2003 While I do think a code translation tag would be prone to questions asking to convert code from one language to another, which we don't like, there's also a possibility of code that does this translation, which isn't, in itself, bad to ask about. Do these questions actually exist? That's something we need to check.

Comment: @Dukeling There's also the [tag:source-to-source] tag, which is about automatic code translation. There are plenty of interesting questions about automatic code translation tools.